# uploading flash with asp server component

Tags: asp-classic

I upload image files using aspupload component. I was wondering if its possible to upload flash files with a component as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload any kind of files.. there are no restrictions..

If you are using code from their examples make sure that they have not hard-coded in their examples checks for the specific file extensions.. you can easily remove/alter those..